# Convex Functionals Weak Inferior Semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I don't understand the step $\underline{\lim}f(x_n)=\lim f(x_m)$ in the prove.

[image]

the subsequence in the prove is from Banach-Sacks below, which is the subsequence of a weakly convergent sequence, whose arithmetical means $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m x_{n_k}$ convergent.

[image]

Firstly how can we know that $f(x_m)$ convergent? From the definition $f(\cdot)$is just a continuous convex functional which may not be linear.

Secondly, why the $=$ holds? Since $x_m$ is just a subsequence of $x_n$, we have $\underline{\lim}f(x_n) \le \lim f(x_m)$.

Please help me!